# Can we create energy from car tires using moving electrical charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electricity, charge

Suppose that we put electric charges in car tires. Now when we drive the car, the charges will be moving on a circular path, viewed from the reference frame of the car. Therefore, they create a magnetic field. Can we use this magnetic field to generate energy while driving?

Comment: The energy "generated" would be taken away from the rotational energy of the wheel, so it would be slowing down the car a bit.

Comment: Why would it slow down the rotational energy? I did not intend the charges to be heavier than the normal tire

Comment: Because the energy comes from somewhere, and that is ultimately the engine driving the wheels. Just like your alternator (a better way to get electrical energy from rotation) is a load on you engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach would be very ineffective as most of the energy would radiate away from the vehicle.

A more effective approach is simply to use the alternator that is already part of every car. This is designed to efficiently convert mechanical energy to electrical energy.

Neither approach “creates” energy. Energy is conserved so it is neither created nor destroyed. The energy comes from the mechanical energy of the vehicle and so it will unavoidably reduce the efficiency of the vehicle.

Comment: You've just invented regenerative braking. Unfortunately, you can't patent it, as it is already in use by millions of electric and hybrid vehicles ツ.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have modified my question a bit, because I would like to know how the mechanical energy is converted to radiation. Could you answer that also?

Comment: @Riemann it is against the site policy to modify the question in a way that invalidates existing answers after valid answers to the original question have been received. I have reverted the question back to the version I answered. What you are looking for is the Abraham-Lorentz force: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham–Lorentz_force  For circular motion this force acts in the direction opposite the velocity. So it acts as a drag on the wheel